# Displaying an error in a DIV element if the text entered in a password field is too long

Tags: html

How do you display a error depending on the length of the text inputted to a password field? For example if a user inputted 10 characters but the limit was 5 "Limit is 5 characters" would be displayed in a DIV. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
<title>Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <span class="main_text">Textbox</span><br>
    <input name="textbox1" type="password" class="textbox1" placeholder="Enter Password" autofocus><br><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Omar.

Here is a example of what I mean:
[image: Example]

Comment: Do you want it to show as they submit or as they type?

Comment: i dont think that php is needed here !! for faster  performance  use jscript...

Comment: You need an event listener then.

Comment: Yes I agree with @VedantTerkar you want to validate on client side(JS). of course you should double check that on the server level(PHP).

Comment: How do you do that? I'm a beginner.

Comment: Why would you ever want to limit the length of a password field? You're just asking for a data breach...

Comment: I'm just trying to test something.

Comment: @ExTrEeMeO i'm sorry i was  unable to answer correctly and fastly but my keyboard is not working thus i'm using onScreen keyboard.. i've updated my answer for `onKeyUp` event. please check it and jscript section in that..

Comment: Thank you very much @VedantTerkar It works very smooth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i think it'll help you.

In PHP:

```
<?php

if(strlen($_POST['textbox1']) > 16)
      echo 'Limit is 16 characters';
   else
      // log in
?>
```

In JavaScript:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function passwordCheck(y){
    var x = y.value;
    if(x.length>5) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="<font color='red'>Limit is 16 characters</font>";
    } else {
        if(x.length<=16) {
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="";
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <span class="main_text">Textbox</span><br>
    <input name="textbox1" onkeyup="passwordCheck(this);" type="password" class="textbox1" placeholder="Enter Password" autofocus><br><br>
<div id="error"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope  it'll  help  you.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` is what you are looking for. It counts letters in the string.

```
<?php 
   if(strlen($_POST['textbox1']) > 5) {
      echo 'Limit is 5 characters';
   }
   else {
      // log in
   }
?>
```

jQuery solution, i think more elegant:

```
$('.textbox1').keydown(function() {
    if($(this).length > 5) {
        $('#error_div').html('Limit is 5 characters');
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you add jQuery?

Comment: Put jQuery part to your `script` tags in your `head` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript keyup event. Which check length of the text box..

Comment: I tried. The error doesn't appear.

Comment: Can u post your code here??

Comment: It's okay, I've found a solution. But thanks anyway!

Comment: My plesure. I faced same problem when I am learning javascript and php

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  Added `<form>` tag and `submit` button

```
                <form action="index.php" method="post">
                    <div class="container">
                            <span class="main_text">Textbox</span><br>                              

                           <input name="textbox1" type="password" class="textbox1" placeholder="Enter Password" autofocus  onkeyup="PasswordChecker(this)"><br><br>
                            <span id="passwordCheck"></span>
                           <?php                           
                              if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                                if(strlen($_POST['textbox1']) > 5){
                                    echo 'Limit is 5 characters';
                                }
                              }
                           ?>
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
               </form>
```

Javascript:

```
   function PasswordChecker(d){
         if(d.value.length>5){
           document.getElementById("passwordCheck").innerHTML = 'Password limit is 5';
        }

     }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it as the user types?

Comment: @ExTrEeMeO, I have updated my answer, use full code

Answer (score 0):

You need understand 2 layers:

- usability layer: put some Javascript, HTML codes into your page to turn it more easy to use.
- security layer: put a Webservice Language (php, c#, python, etc.) to avoid error on your data, malicious injection, etc.

So what you need is both:

Using Javascript you will use attribute `object.length` and on PHP the attribute `strlen($variable)`

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is validation form data on server-side and client-side. Always implement rule that says: "Never trust users".
Your php-code is:

```
<?php  
   $errors = [];                         
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      if(isset($_POST['password']) && strlen($_POST['password']) > 5){
        $errors[] = 'Limit is 5 characters';
      }
   }
 ?>
<div class="container">
  <php if(!empty($errors)): >
    <div class="messages"><?php join('<br/>', $errors) ?></div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <span class="main_text">Textbox</span><br>
    <input name="password" type="password" class="textbox1" placeholder="Enter Password" autofocus><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the error appear as the user types?

Comment: Yes of course. But you must use Ajax technology look here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and here http://api.jquery.com/on/